# Some questions for counting alphabet

Tags: arrays, c, ascii

im very new to C and got some questions about this part of a programm.

I know that this is counting letters but how does this work if you compare the variable c and 'a'.

c is zero and a would be decimal 97 in the ASCII code so no if statement would be true anyway?

```
if ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ){
            c-='a';
            A[c]++;
```

Also what does A[c]++; do when there is only 1 element in the array int A[27] = {0}; ?

````
int c=0;
int A[27] = {0};

int main()
{
    
    do{

        if ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ){
            c-='a';
            A[c]++;
        }
        else if ( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ){
            c-='A';
            A[c]++;
        }
        else if (c == '\n'){
            continue;
        }
        else{
            A[26]++;
        }

    } while ((c = fgetc(data1)) != EOF);


    for (c = 0; c < sizeof A / sizeof A[0] - 1; c++)
    {
        printf("%c:%02d\t", c+'a', A[c]);
    }

}```
````

Comment: `int A[27] = {0};` defines an array (named `A`) with 27 elements (all) of type `int`. The 1st element (`A[0]`) is explicitly assigned the value `0` and the other 26 elements are implicitly initialized with `0` (there is no partial initialization in C). Note the array indexes, for the 27 elements, go from `0` to `26`.

Comment: c = 0 is not the same as c = '0'.  The character '0' has ASCII numeric value 48.  Both are less than 'A' which is 65.

Comment: @stark Thank you for help but i do not get it when the if statement is true c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'. so char a always would be bigger than c ( 0 and asci value) ?

Answer (score 0):

This code is not very good. You should use standard functions to detect letters.

```
int main(void)
{    
    int c;
    size_t A[26] = {0};
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)
        if(isalpha(c = toupper((unsigned char)c))) A[c - 'A']++;

    for (c = 0; c < sizeof A / sizeof A[0]; c++)
        printf("%c:%zu%c", c +'A', A[c], !((c + 1) % 4) ? '\n' : '\t');
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jrTf751vW

Answer (score 0):

`c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'`  is testing whether `c` contains a lower-case alphabetic character, which must be in the range of 'a' to 'z'.  If c is less than 'a' the first test fails, if it is greater than 'z' the second test fails.

Comment: But if i have value zero for c so the if statement would always fail? Also c-='a';  would be 0 subtracted with asci value from a, so c would be -97 then or not? Sorry i really dont get it.

Comment: A new value for c is read on each loop:  `c = fgetc(data1)`

Answer (score 0):

> Also what does A[c]++; do when there is only 1 element in the array
> int A[27] = {0};

In this array

```
int A[27] = {0};
```

there are 27 elements. The first element A[0] is explicitly initialized by zero and all other elements are implicitly initialized also by zero. So all elements are set to 0.

In the first iteration of the do-while loop the variable `c` is equal to `0`

```
int c=0;
```

So as the variable does not contain a letter (lower case or upper case) then the control will be passed to this else statement

```
    else{
        A[26]++;
    }
```

That is all non-letter characters are countered in the element A[26] of the array.

If the variable `c` contains a letter as for example 'a' then the index of the element of the array is calculated like `c - 'a'` provided that all letters follows each other with the step equal to 1.

So the occurrence of the letter 'a' (or 'A' ) is calculated in the element A[0] of the array, the occurrence of the letter 'b' (or 'B') is calculated in the array element A[1] and so on due to these statements

```
        c-='a';
        A[c]++;
```

and

```
        c-='A';
        A[c]++;
```

Then the occurrences of letters are outputted in this for loop

```
for (c = 0; c < sizeof A / sizeof A[0] - 1; c++)
{
    printf("%c:%02d\t", c+'a', A[c]);
}
```

Pay attention to that in general it is not necessary that all letters follow each other with the step equal to 1. For example for the EBCDIC coding of characters this is not true.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have one more question: You say that everything that does not contain a letter goes to index A[26]++; but how much can i save in [26] ? for example if there are occuring 2 or 3 numbers or special characters with fgetc.

Comment: @skruf922 The element type of the array is int. So each element of the array can contain the maximum value equal to INT_MAX.